# Python Crash Course Alien Invasion | AttributeError: 'Bullet' object has no attribute 'speed_factor'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing Python Crash Course Alien invasion and when I test this code, an error pops out saying that "Bullet" has no object "speed_factor"

I've been trying for so long to find out why, checked multiple times the code and even compared it to other codes, but it all seems fine.

The game code (alien_invasion.py):

```
import sys
import game_functions as gf
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
from pygame.sprite import Group

def run_game():
# Initialize pygame, settings, and screen object.
 pygame.init()
 ai_settings = Settings()



screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
# Make a ship.
ship = Ship(screen, ai_settings)
bullets = Group()

# Background color
bg_color = (230, 230, 230)


while True:

    gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
    gf.update_screen(ai_settings, bullets, screen, ship)

    gf.check_events(ship, screen, ship, bullets)
    ship.update(ai_settings)
    bullets.update()


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)

    ship.blitme()
    pygame.display.flip()

run_game()
```

Settings code (settings.py):

```
class Settings():
def __init__(self):
    self.screen_width = 1200
    self.screen_height = 800
    self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
    self.ship_speed_factor = 2

    self.bullet_speed_factor = 1
    self.bullet_width = 3
    self.bullet_height = 12
    self.bullet_color = (60, 60, 60)
    self.bullet_limit = 5
```

Ship code (ship.py):

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Ship(Sprite):
def __init__(self, screen, ai_settings):
    self.screen = screen
    self.ai_settings = ai_settings
    self.image = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\alien invasion\ship.bmp')
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
    self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom
    self.moving_right = False
    self.moving_left = False
    self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)
    self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor



def update(self, ai_settings):
    self.ai_settings = ai_settings
    if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
        self.rect.centerx += 1
        self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
    if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
        self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        self.rect.centerx -= 1


def blitme(self):
    self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Bullet code (bullet.py):

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Bullet(Sprite):

def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, ship):
    super().__init__()
    self.screen = screen
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, ai_settings.bullet_width, ai_settings.bullet_height)
    self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx
    self.rect.top = ship.rect.top
    self.y = float(self.rect.y)
    self.color = ai_settings.bullet_color
    self.ship_speed_factor = ai_settings.bullet_speed_factor

def update(self):
    self.y -= self.speed_factor
    self.rect.y = self.y


def draw_bullet(self):
    pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

game_functions.py:

```
import pygame
from bullet import Bullet

def check_keydown_events(event, ship, ai_settings, screen, bullets):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        new_bullet =  Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
        bullets.add(new_bullet)

def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False

def check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event,ship, ai_settings, screen, bullets)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                ship.moving_right = True

            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                ship.moving_left = True

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
           if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
             ship.moving_right = False

           elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
             ship.moving_left = False

def update_screen(ai_settings, bullets, screen, ship):

    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
        ship.blitme()
```

Error log:

```
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\alien invasion\bullet.py", line 17, in update
self.y -= self.speed_factor
AttributeError: 'Bullet' object has no attribute 'speed_factor'
```

I would really appreciate any kind of help as this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `__init__` of your `Bullet` class, you're setting `self.ship_speed_factor` but in its `update` method you're trying to do `self.y -= self.speed_factor`.
I guess you're just using a wrong field name, in which case you should do either of:

- replace `self.y -= self.speed_factor` with `self.y -= self.ship_speed_factor` in `update`
- replace `self.ship_speed_factor = ...` with `self.speed_factor = ...` in `__init__`

Comment: Yes problem fixed! Thank you, although now the bullets aren't firing when I press the spacebar. Even though it is set for it to do so. Would you know why is that? Thank you

Comment: No unfortunately I don't know `pygame`, but I would probably start with putting a breakpoint in `check_keydown_events` and starting the debugger, or adding a bunch of `print` statements in `check_keydown_events` to verify that it captures the keypress at all, what key it got, and if it enters the appropriate `if`. If this is looking good then I'd proceed to investigating why adding a bullet to `bullets` doesn't make it appear. I'd probably start with googling and reading `pygame`'s documentation.